# Error after changing from sqllite3 data base to PostgreSQL

Tags: django, postgresql, sqlite

I have been running into some error after changing from sqllite3 database to PostgreSQL.Here  is some of the error.

```
ValueError at /post/None/
Field 'id' expected a number but got 'None'.
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/post/None/
Django Version: 3.1.6
Exception Type: ValueError
Exception Value:    
Field 'id' expected a number but got 'None'.
Exception Location: /home/mike/.local/share/virtualenvs/mercy-TKuV6FoL/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py, line 1778, in get_prep_value
Python Executable:  /home/mike/.local/share/virtualenvs/mercy-TKuV6FoL/bin/python
Python Version: 3.7.5
Python Path:    
['/home/mike/Web/mercy',
 '/usr/lib/python37.zip',
 '/usr/lib/python3.7',
 '/usr/lib/python3.7/lib-dynload',
 '/home/mike/.local/share/virtualenvs/mercy-TKuV6FoL/lib/python3.7/site-packages']
Server time:    Sat, 03 Apr 2021 06:52:29 +0300
```

and here is some code in the views.py file

```
def post(request, id):
    category_count = get_category_count()
    most_recent = Post.objects.order_by('-timestamp')[:3]
    post = get_object_or_404(Post, id=id)
    if request.user.is_authenticated:
        PostView.objects.get_or_create(user=request.user, post=post)
    form = CommentForm(request.POST or None)
    if request.method == "POST":
        if form.is_valid():
            form.instance.user = request.user
            form.instance.post = post
            form.save()
    context = {
        'form': form,
        'post': post,
        'most_recent': most_recent,
        'category_count': category_count,
    }
    return render(request, 'post.html', context)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your GET request on post url does not have any id param :

```
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/post/None/
```

While your method is expecting one:

```
def post(request, id):
    category_count = get_category_count()
    most_recent = Post.objects.order_by('-timestamp')[:3]
    post = get_object_or_404(Post, id=id)
```

Your url should be /post/1 ,post/56 etc.